# I can not use the function 'PutText of OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

When I try to use the function putText library OpenCV I get those errors:

> 1.'putText': identifier not found.
>
> 2.identifier "putText" is undefined.

My code:

```
putText(image1,"ff",cv::Point(25, 50), 30, CV_RGB(0, 0, 255));
```

**Can someone explain me why?**

Comment: Could you show more code? I assume the error is on the previous line of the line you show in your post. Also you code don't match the Documentation: `C++: void putText(Mat& img, const string& text, Point org, int fontFace, double fontScale, Scalar color, int thickness=1, int lineType=8, bool bottomLeftOrigin=false )`

Comment: it's the part of the putText. what show?

Comment: did you try cv::putText?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't shared any actual snippets I will just post you the snippet that should get you on top of things, given that you already have OpenCV matrix loaded and ready for writing the test.

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>

using namespace cv;

// ...
Mat img;
double scale = 0.45;
Point org = cvPoint(img.cols / 7, img.rows / 14);
putText(img, "sometext", org, FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, scale, CV_RGB(0, 255, 255), 1, CV_AA);
```

The declaration of function itself is located in "opencv2/core/core_c.h"

Comment: I did all it and this is not did

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using OpenCV 3.x instead of OpenCV 2.x...

You need to add this:

`#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"`

`putText` has been moved to the imgproc module in OpenCV 3.x